# Automating Instagram Posting

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to automate uploading on instagram with python, I found instapy-cli online, but it doesn't seem to work anymore, because of API changes on instagram's side. Is there any alternatives?

Sorry if the question is elementary, I'm relatively new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IG Content Publishing API to post content for IG Business Accounts
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

There is no official API for posting to regular IG accounts.